Filtering payment methods doesn't work with Checkout Blocks
Whenever I wanted to remove a specific payment method programmatically in Woocommerce, it was simple as this:
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'remove_payment_options', 10, 1);
function remove_payment_options( $available_gateways ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
        return $available_gateways;
    }
    if (my_logic_goes_here) {
        unset($available_gateways['cod']); //remove cash on delivery
    }
    return $available_gateways;

However, this add_filter doesn't work with the new Checkout Blocks feature. I searched the documentation and I couldn't find any new filter for that. Is there any way to remove a payment method like before?
